# Android- Returning data from list activity

Tags: java, android, list

My application has a main activity which can spawn one of four list activities, the goal is to have the user select items from the lists one after another and upon `submit` from the main activity push those choices to a database.

**Issue: I am unsure how to return and store the results of the lists in the main activity.**

I am not using a list view for the other activities as it wouldn't allow for a 'done' button on the same screen.

So far this is what I have

*Main:*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listOneSub);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listTwoSub);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listThreeSub);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listFourSub);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == button1) {
            startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.SecondActivity"));
        } else if (v == button2) {
            startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.ThirdActivity"));
        } else if (v == button3) {
            startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.FourthActivity"));
        } else if (v == button4) {
            startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.FifthActivity"));
        }
    }
```

*List Activities (all four are similar, they just have different items):*

```
String [] lstOne;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);
        ListView lstView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.android_listOne);
        lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        //lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lstOne = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.one);

        lstView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, lstOne));

        }




    public void onClick(View view){
        ListView lstView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.android_listOne);

        String itemsSelected =  "Selected items: \n";
        for(int i=0; i<lstView.getCount(); i++){
            if(lstView.isItemChecked(i)){
                itemsSelected += lstView.getItemAtPosition(i) + "\n";
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, itemsSelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
```

The lists are being generated from the `strings.xml` file.  I would like to update the main view under the buttons to display what has been chosen from each list before submitting.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` and `onActivityResult` will be called on your main.

I would also suggest merging these 4 classes into 1 and sending identifier of string array you want to display. Code duplication is very bad.

Comment: Ah that is true, am I able to send information like that to an activity? I did it with duplicate classes because I was not aware you could send parameters to activities.

Comment: Read about [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and putExtra.

Comment: Reading about intents will be useful, although I am finding nothing one how I can send an identifier with my activity request.  Normal java you would just alter the constructor for a class when your instantiating the class but this is far more convoluted.

Comment: This should help: developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html Check Build an Intent and Receive the Intent parts.

Comment: The issue I am running into with android is having to start over, again and again, because apparently there are so many different ways to do something that I would think is cut and dry.  Getting a little frustrated, thank you for the help.

Comment: I felt the same way back when I was starting. I often meet devs that don't know about startActivityForResult after 3 months. This platform is fun when you get to know each other well.